# Given an integer sequence, show that the set of all roots of integers from it is dense in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

> Let $\mathbb{W}=\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}.$ Let $\langle a_i \rangle_{i\in\mathbb{W}}$ be an integer sequence with $0≤a_0,$ and $a_n<a_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{W}.$ Let $\mathbb{A}=\{(a_n)^{\frac{1}{k}}:(n,k)\in\mathbb{W}\times\mathbb{N}\}.$ That is, $\mathbb{A}$ is the set of all $k$th roots of all integers from the sequence, where $k$ ranges over all natural numbers. Show that $\mathbb{A}$ is dense in $(0,\infty).$

I actually do not if the statement is even true. However, I've proven a weaker version of the statement. If we restrict the sequence to satisfy $a_{n+1}-a_n≤m$ for some fixed constant $m$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{W},$ we can easily show that the set is dense. Take arbitrary $x,y\in (0,\infty),$ with $x<y.$ The function $f(p)=y^p-x^p$ is an increasing function of $p.$ Pick the least natural number $p'$ such that $f(p')>m.$ In that case, there exists some $a_i$ satisfying $x^{p'}<a_i<y^{p'}.$ Taking $p'$th roots, we are done.

How do we deal with the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show that the set is dense in $(1,\infty)$ and leave it to you to do the same for $(0,1)$.

Let $1<a<b<\infty$. Then the length of the interval $(\frac {ln a_n} {\ln b},\frac {\ln a_n} {\ln a})$ is $\frac {\ln a_n} {\ln a}-\frac {\ln a_n} {\ln b}$ and this length exceeds $1$ if $n$ is large enough. Hence, it contains an integer $k$ (which is necessarily positve). We now have

$$\frac {\ln a_n} {\ln b}<k<\frac {\ln a_n} {\ln a}.$$ This gives $a<a_n^{1/k}<b$ so every open interval in $(1,\infty)$ intersects $\mathbb A$.